# Chapter header bugged through document

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm looking to make a new book-like chapter format in which there's an image before the chapter's name and came up with a code by redefining `chapter` to do just that through a `tikzpicture` but now the problem is that throughout the document, the chapter name in the header of each page is 'Contents' and not the corresponding chapter's title. Does anyone have an idea how could I correct it, so that the header is the current chapter's title?

Heres's a MWE of my document.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}

\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{
    \clearforchapter
    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \chapterheadstart
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, path image/.style={
            path picture={
                \node[xshift=-1cm] at (path picture bounding box.center) {
                \includegraphics{#2}
        };}}]
        \draw [path image=#2] (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth, 0);
        \draw (-1.5,0) circle (0pt) node [right, rectangle, rounded corners=8pt, fill=blue]
            {\Huge\bfseries\color{yellow}\thechapter\; #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter\hspace{0.5em} #1}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    }
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First}{nilum}

\lipsum[1]\newpage
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Second}{nilum}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you redefine the `\chapter` command mess up the default format and header update. I believe the reason you use the `memomir` class is to follow the default format of this class. Otherwise, there are so many other choices (e.g., book, report). So I don't recommend you to use `geometery` package. If you really want to customize the chapter heading in `memomir` class, you should use the those predefined the commands in `memomir`. In this way it won't mess the format and header update. Also the star version of chapter heading (such as `contents`) also have the same format as the numbered one. Use this method, you won't have a second argument to specify the chapter image. So a command `\chapterimage` is defined. The chapter image can be changed by renew the command `\chapterimage` before you enter a new chapter. Even the following method achieve the goal but it is not recommended.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\def\chapnumcontents{\thechapter\; }}
\renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{\def\chapnumcontents{}}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
\chaptitlefont\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture, 
overlay, 
path image/.style={
path picture={
\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics{\chapterimage}};
}
}
]

\draw [path image=\chapterimage](current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth-2cm-1pt, 0);

\node [rectangle, rounded corners=8pt, fill=blue,anchor=west] at (-1,0) {\color{yellow}\chapnumcontents#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1cm}
\newcommand\chapterimage{example-image}
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\renewcommand\chapterimage{example-image-a}
\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1]\newpage
\lipsum[2]

\renewcommand\chapterimage{example-image-b}
\chapter{Second}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]